# Loadtesting Node.js with loadtest : how to set requests per second?

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I'm trying to loadtest Node.js app using loadtest - [loadtest -npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest)

What I want to achieve is to send 10 requests per second (no more than 10 is crucial) for the duration of 300 seconds.

I have tried this:

loadtest -t 300 --rps 10 [url]

But unfortunately it's not working: only one request is being send to Node.js.

Problem is the same for:

loadtest -n 3000 --rps 10 [url]

Without using option --rps loadtest continuously sends requests to application, with either -n or -t option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also to have a concurrency set with "-c".
Right now it sends only 1 message and waits for it to come back
You should add a concurrency of at least 10 (10 unanswered messages sent at most before you can send more)

Comment: With: loadtest -t 300 -c 10 -n 3000 --rps 10 <url> the total sum of 10 requests is send to Node.js. Also, at which condition does loadtest count message as answered? Node.js is actually not sending anything back, only statusCode of response is set to 200 and statusMessage to 'OK'.

Comment: It tests HTTP requests which have to have a response, if there is no response then it will not send another request. A HTTP 200 OK response is enough, does not have to contain a response body.
I ran your command and it seems fine, note that if you're using a HTTPS url with a self signed certificate you'll need to add --insecure
https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest

Comment: Sorry for late response, but the problem was in the lack of response body. Thank you for solving my problem.